# How can I customize qweb report for existing records odoo 10?

Tags: odoo, odoo-10

I customized `external_layout`, it's working fine with new records. But not for older records. Old invoices which are not in `draft` state still printing in default `external_layout`.
How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The report settings provide a property to reload from attachment(You'll need to enable developer options).

The settings are found at "Settings => Technical => Reporting => Reporting"
(The invoice report can be found as "Invoices")

When this setting is checked it won't create a new one but serve you the old report.

You have two options:

1. You could delete the old attachment on the attachment dropdown (enabled by the document module) on
   the specific record and click on the bin icon behind the old report.
2. Uncheck the setting in the configuration. Then Odoo would create a new report every time you'd print an invoice. (This also has as result that the amount of attachments build up)

Answer (score 1):

Invoices are saved as attachment in default odoo configuration. That means: if there already is a printed pdf in the attachments, odoo will print them instead of render a new pdf. By deleting the attachment, odoo will print a new pdf.

Comment: CZoellener, How can i delete those attachemnts? 
and,odoo render the new changes even if the document is in draft state. Why?.

Comment: The report is configured that way. Just look into the report formular view for it. And maybe you have to install the module "knowledge" to see the attachments.